# Replace \" with " in json transformation

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

How to replace `\"` with `"` JOLT json transformation.

## input json

```json
{
  "cpf": "[{\"property\":\"PQR\",\"value\":\"-\"},{\"property\":\"Exclude\",\"value\":\"-\"},{\"property\":\"Test\",\"value\":null},{\"property\":\"Test\",\"value\":null},{\"property\":\"Requested\",\"value\":\"PNT\"},{\"property\":\"Flag\",\"value\":\"TR\"},{\"property\":\"Name\",\"value\":\"Some Sentense\"},{\"property\":\"Length\",\"value\":null},{\"property\":\"ID\",\"value\":\"098789\"},{\"property\":\"BUS ID\",\"value\":\"123456988433\"}]"
}
```

## Expected json

```json
{
  "cpf":[
    {
      "property":"PQR",
      "value":"-"
    },
    {
      "property":"Exclude",
      "value":"-"
    },
    {
      "property":"Test",
      "value":null
    },
    {
      "property":"Test",
      "value":null
    },
    {
      "property":"Requested",
      "value":"PNT"
    },
    {
      "property":"Flag",
      "value":"TR"
    },
    {
      "property":"Name",
      "value":"Some Sentense"
    },
    {
      "property":"Length",
      "value":null
    },
    {
      "property":"ID",
      "value":"098789"
    },
    {
      "property":"BUS ID",
      "value":"123456988433"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried following specs but didnt working

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "cpf": "=split('\"',@(1,cpf))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=join('',@(1,cpf))"
    }
  }
]
```

I am not getting in second operation how to add only `"` without escape character

Comment: You shouldn't be manipulating that string.  That's JSON embedded in JSON.  You need to decode, and then decode the contents.

Comment: whole flow is codeless, we are using it in NiFi, so decoding would be challenge here

Comment: You can't do this with straight Jolt.  Jolt does have a "java" operation that can pass the unit into Java code.  Perhaps you could do the nested decode there.

Comment: Jolt is a non-starter. Look like a task for a script, maybe just `sed`, run over the file. Or have the source serve it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Prasad Jolt doesn't support replace functionality yet, I would prefer going with Java in this usecase because a simple String replace will solve this issue.

```
String inputJson= ""{\n" +
                "  \"cpf\": \"[{\\\"property\\\":\\\"PQR\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"-\\\"},{\\\"property\\\":\\\"Exclude\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"-\\\"},{\\\"property\\\":\\\"Test\\\",\\\"value\\\":null},{\\\"property\\\":\\\"Test\\\",\\\"value\\\":null},{\\\"property\\\":\\\"Requested\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"PNT\\\"},{\\\"property\\\":\\\"Flag\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"TR\\\"},{\\\"property\\\":\\\"Name\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"Some Sentense\\\"},{\\\"property\\\":\\\"Length\\\",\\\"value\\\":null},{\\\"property\\\":\\\"ID\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"098789\\\"},{\\\"property\\\":\\\"BUS ID\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"123456988433\\\"}]\"\n" +
                "}"";

inputJson.replace("\\","").replace("]\"","]").replace("\"[","[")
```

This will generate the expected Json Array output.